# Is it possible to test the migration from one app version to a new one using Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

While manually testing the app that I'm about to release, I found an error when migrating the old SQLite DB to the new Room DB for a specific device

I'd really like to be able to do this automatically on multiple devices.

Is this possible to achieve this with Firebase Test Lab? So basically first install the old .apk and after install the new one

How do you test the transition from an old app to a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Test Lab can support this exact use case. You can push the older DB file to an FTL device before a test runs using the `--other-files=` option, and then install and test the updated app, but I'm not sure that achieves what you are looking for.

There is also an option to push `--additional-apks=`, but I've never seen that used to install different versions of the same app.